# compiling from headers <string>, <stack> are not giving any output

Tags: c++, powershell, terminal

Can you help me?

Including STL header files in C++ such as `<string>`, `<stack>`, `<bits/stdc++.h>`, etc does not give any output. But `<iostream>` is working fine.

For `<string>` I have tried `std::string` in declaration, too.

I have included `C:\MinGW\bin` to my path.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string str = "hello";
    // string str = "hi";
    cout << str;
}
```

My Stack program look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stack<int> s;
    s.push(5);
    cout << s.top();
}
```

I have checked my g++ version by

```
g++ --version
g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

In both the cases my PowerShell looks like this (powershell doesn't do anything after the `./hello.exe`):

[image]

Comment: Try changing to `cout << str << endl;` (Although I'm not sure why this is needed as stdout should be flushed when the program exits)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Windows shell doesn't handle very well lines not terminated by a newline character IIRC. So yes, appending `'\n'` should work.

Comment: Might be due this is not a really OEP because you not returning anything from `main()`

Comment: Just curious ... in your statement: "... my PowerShell looks like this"  mentions ./a.exe. ... but the reference (at imgur.com) shows "-o hello" and then "./hello.exe" (not ./a.exe).  In Ubuntu,  "-o hello" would generate an executable file with no suffix, just "hello".  Does your compiler automatically append the ".exe"?

Comment: @M.Sol There's an implicit `return 0;` at the end of `main` in C++.

Comment: @M.Sol What is "OEP"?

Comment: @2785528 Sorry I have changed it to ./hello.exe . Yes the compiled code has extension .exe in Windows

Comment: @2785528 Compilers on Windows usually add the ".exe" suffix. It's pretty much the Windows version of setting the executable bit.

Comment: I've had similar problems before. I believe the problem is that windows is silently ignoring the error it has when starting your program. Most likely windows is failing to find one or more DLLs provided by MinGW when loading your program. Typically you can get Windows to not ignore the error by double-clicking the EXE in the file explorer

Comment: @molbdnilo OEP aka OriginalEntryPoint and the `return 0;` implicit is only viable in C99 and C11 standards

Comment: @Howard Thank you for your suggestion. Double-clicking the EXE gives error as "The procedure entry point _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringcSt11char_traitsIcESalcEEC1EPKcRKS3_ could not be located in the  dynamic link library"

Comment: @M.Sol The implicit return has been in C++ since forever. (And please spell out obscure, platform-specific acronyms.)

Comment: @shanthosh that looks like it's having trouble finding your c++ standard library. Look for the one in your MinGW install folder and you can copy and paste it next to your executable to get the correct behavior. Obviously that's a temporary fix, you'll want to look into Windows other mechanisms for DLL lookup for a more permanent fix.

Comment: @Howard Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I) Look for the `libstdc++-6.dll` located in the path `C:\MinGW\bin`.
II) Copy and paste it in the executable directory i.e., where `hello.exe` is located.
III) Now Execute it.